# PyLint wrongly says an object missing certain attributes

Tags: python, code-analysis, pylint

In my code I use object from compiled extensions (in my case, [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net)). I use PyLint to analyze the code. PyLint complains about missing attributes (such as igraph's `Graph.adjacent`), while it clearly exists (the code runs without errors). What might be the cause for this messages?

Here is some test code

```
import igraph
gr = igraph.Graph(10)#create a graph with 10 vertices
edges = gr.es #no pylint errors
vertices = gr.vs #no pylint errors
print gr.are_connected(0, 1) #pylint error E1101
print gr.adjacent(0) #pylint error E1101
```

And this is the output of pylint:

```
************* Module temp
C0111:  1: Missing docstring
C0103:  2: Invalid name "gr" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C0103:  3: Invalid name "edges" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C0103:  4: Invalid name "vertices" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
E1101:  5: Instance of 'Graph' has no 'are_connected' member
E1101:  6: Instance of 'Graph' has no 'adjacent' member
```

PS: igraph **is** in my PYTHONPATH

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya Thank you, added example

Comment: is igraph on your python path?

Comment: I assume you mean E1101 (and not E11011 which I don't know about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a compiled C extension, there is little Pylint can do, as it cannot analyze the source code. Can you print igraph.Graph.are_connected in an interactive shell ? If not, it means that the library probably does some weird things at instantiation time or that the methods are introspected.

In any case this is a tricky problem for pylint.

You could use the patch provided on http://www.logilab.org/ticket/73978 (recently included in the dev tree) or ignore E1101 with inlined directives.